# How to write a Ruby program using only "a-z", "A-Z", ".", "\n" and " "

Tags: ruby, string, data-conversion, puts

I am trying to resolve some Ruby challenge and I have big problem with some low level (I suppose?) digits characters conversion.

> Just imagine, that you need to **write program**, that prints on your screen sentence ex.:
>
> *"Jon Doe was born in 2017!"*
>
> using only following characters **[a-zA-Z.\n ]** (small & big letters, dot, space and new line)

In fact, I have no idea how should I even start to look for the answer.

Is it some kind of using `pack` / `unpack` method? or is there any trival solution that I can't find?

There is a reason why "write program" was bolded. Question is, what is the simplest definition of *program* in Ruby?

Comment: This would be a nice task at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a program that prints a string using only letters, dot, space and newline might seem impossible at first, but it is actually not that hard.

Lowercase and uppercase letters allow you to invoke [`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html) methods (like `print` and `puts`) as well as [keywords](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) like `nil`, `false` and `true`. A dot allows you to invoke methods with an explicit receiver. Space allows you to pass an argument to a method. Newline separates commands.

Let's try to get an "a":

```
false                            #=> false
false.inspect                    #=> "false"
false.inspect.chars              #=> ["f", "a", "l", "s", "e"]
false.inspect.chars.rotate       #=> ["a", "l", "s", "e", "f"]
false.inspect.chars.rotate.first #=> "a"
```

Now lets print "abc":

```
print false.inspect.chars.rotate.first
print false.inspect.chars.rotate.first.succ
print false.inspect.chars.rotate.first.succ.succ
puts
```

Output:

```
abc
```

You get the idea.

And yes, it's also possible to print spaces, punctuation and numbers using a similar approach. But I leave that to you. Take a look at the available methods and be creative.

Additional points for figuring out how to print a string without using space, just `[a-zA-Z.\n]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for great answer! With your advices I have been able to resolve my problem in couple of minutes :)

Comment: @coder1991 I'm curious – how did you print `2017!`?